# Iterating over an ArrayList which contains Bean objects with c:foreach,doesn't work

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, jstl

I'm iterating over ArrayList in JSP, which contains objects of a Bean.I want to use getter() to extract information from that object.ProductID is one of the attribute which I'm interested in.
I'm using JSTL for this purpose.The code is as follows:

```
<c:forEach items="repo" var="element">
 <jsp:useBean id="element"  scope="page" class="com.ResponseBean"/> 
Product:<jsp:getProperty property="ProductID" name="element"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Where repo is ArrayList which contains objects of ResponseBean.

```
List<ResponseBean> repo=new ArrayList<ResponseBean>(10);
```

Code of ResponseBean is as follows:

```
public class ResponseBean implements java.io.Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String ProductID;
public String getProductID() {
    return ProductID;
}
public void setProductID(String productID) {
    ProductID = productID;
}
```

But I'm getting following excepion

```
HTTP Status 500 - Cannot find any information on property 'ProductID' in a bean of type 'com.ResponseBean'

type Exception report

message Cannot find any information on property 'ProductID' in a bean of type 'com.ResponseBean'

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Cannot find any information on property 'ProductID' in a bean of type 'com.ResponseBean'
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.getReadMethod(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:824)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1081)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$GetProperty.accept(Node.java:1125)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2375)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2427)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1784)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1538)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2375)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2427)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2433)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:474)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2375)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3517)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:250)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.52
```

where it is going wrong?

Comment: `Cannot find any information on property 'ProductID' in a bean of type 'com.ResponseBean'` That is almost the answer :)

Comment: Cannot find any information on property 'ProductID' in a bean of type 'com.ResponseBean'

Comment: private String ProductID;    public String getProductID() {
  return ProductID;
 }

Comment: Already have getter() for property ProductID.

Comment: @sureshAtta,@NinadPingle now tell me what is the problem??

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to do this, you can simply use EL

```
<c:forEach items="repo" var="element">
     Product: ${element.productID}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: It shows exception      `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'productID' not found on type java.lang.String`

Comment: please show the `ResponseBean` code, you need public getter/setters, so if you have a atrtibute called `productID` you need `public String getProductID ()`

Comment: Also according to the error message that you posted just above, `repo` seems to be a collection of `String` not `ResponseBean`

Comment: repo contains ReponseBean objects.Object has String field ProductID.

Comment: maybe clean and redeploy your web application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that.

```
<c:forEach items="repo" var="element">
    <c:out value="${element.productID}">
</c:forEach>
```